# Can ESLint - Airbnb be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I don't why I am having such a difficult time trying to install ESLint, and I am starting to think it is because I am on Ubuntu.

Basically, I wanted to use the the [Airbnb JavaScript](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) and/or [Airbnb Ruby](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby) style guide for my code because it inconsistent, there is unused variables everywhere, and `console.log`/ `debugger`'s everywhere, so I want to get a hold of that.

So initially I globally installed eslint, and then installed `eslint-config-airbnb` using

```
(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)
```

[image: And I think it worked...]

I also installed all of these `eslint`, `eslint-plugin-import`, `eslint-plugin-react`, and `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.`

Next, I created - or I think it was generated - the `.eslintrc` file with only

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

I didn't really know what to do afterwards. Like, how do I know if I have the styles installed. I thought the next step would be to some how RUN the `.eslintrc` file so it knows what I want, thus, I did `eslint app` and I also created a script in `package.json` `"lint": "eslint app"` but then it was giving me this issue, that:

`Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'`

And I was told that I shouldn't install it GLOBALLY. **Next**, I removed it globally, and installed it in app directory in the dev tools, and it was giving me this issue:

`bash: /home/dilraj/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/bin/eslint: No such file or directory`

I am starting to think that maybe it's a Ubuntu thing, because every time I google these problems they are from 2013-2015 and it is unclear to me why it is as such :(

> Hold Up!

So I decided to install `npm install -g eslint-config-airbnb` GLOBALLY, and it's giving me some further instructions.

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y". This can happen for a couple different reasons:

1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y is also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-installed plugin.

2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

    npm i eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@latest --save-dev

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install `eslint-config-airbnb-bundle` globally. This is an *Airbnb config* bundled with ESLint for the sake of convenience and for solving some trouble with the installation. You'll also find instructions for Sublime Text 3:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-bundle